# Configuration for restful service request for application/xml media type for spring integration webservice

Tags: spring-integration

While developing webservice for some project requirement using spring integration to cater for the restful request with `application/xml` media type but I am getting the below exception while deploying the web application:

```
Error occurred during deployment: Exception while loading the app : java.lang.IllegalStateException: ContainerBase.addChild: start: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: org.springframework.beans.NotWritablePropertyException: Invalid property 'componentName' of bean class [org.springframework.oxm.jaxb.Jaxb2Marshaller]: Bean property 'componentName' is not writable or has an invalid setter method. Does the parameter type of the setter match the return type of the getter?. Please see server.log for more details.
```

below is the sample configuration to cater web request with media type application/xml:

```
<int:channel id="xmlServiceImplChannel" />
<int:channel id="xmlServiceReqImplChannel" />

<int-http:inbound-gateway request-channel="xmlServiceImplChannel"
    supported-methods="POST" path="/xmlServiceImplReq"/>


<!-- this is require to enrich the header to handle the content-type of 
    type "application/xml" -->
<int:header-enricher input-channel="xmlServiceImplChannel"
    output-channel="xmlServiceReqImplChannel">
    <int:header name="content-type" value="application/xml"></int:header>
</int:header-enricher>

<int:chain input-channel="xmlServiceReqImplChannel">


<oxm:jaxb2-marshaller id="xmlMarshaller" context-path="com.xyz.channel.model"></oxm:jaxb2-marshaller>

<int:service-activator>
    <bean class="com.xyz.channel.model.serviceImpl.xmlServiceImpl"><constructor-arg ref="xmlServiceType"></constructor-arg></bean>
</int:service-activator>

<oxm:jaxb2-marshaller id="xmlMarshaller" context-path="com.xyz.channel.model"></oxm:jaxb2-marshaller>

</int:chain>
```

Please let me know if I am missing some configuration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your issue that you try to use `<oxm:jaxb2-marshaller>` within the `<chain>`, but it can't be done, becauase only `MessageHandler` implementation can be used as `<bean>` there.

For you purpose you should use `<int-xml:marshalling-transformer>` and inject that top level `xmlMarshaller` to that component within `<chain>`:

```
<oxm:jaxb2-marshaller id="xmlMarshaller" context-path="com.xyz.channel.model"></oxm:jaxb2-marshaller>

<int:chain input-channel="xmlServiceReqImplChannel">
   <si-xml:marshalling-transformer marshaller="xmlMarshaller" /> 
   <int:service-activator>
      <bean class="com.xyz.channel.model.serviceImpl.xmlServiceImpl"><constructor-arg     ref="xmlServiceType"></constructor-arg></bean>
   </int:service-activator>

</int:chain>
```

From other side it isn't clear to me what is the reason to use the second marshaller after `<service-activator>`...